# MPAndroidChart - X-axis draw labels only on top

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I want to display X-axis labels only on the top of my chart. How can I do it?

I'm using this code:

```
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
```

And this is result:[image]

Or If I do this

```
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
```

Then I have labels only on the top BUT the bottom line is missing.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bottom line is missing"? Are you talking about the bottom border? Do you want to display top labels while having bottom border, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, bottom border is missing. And yes, I want to display top labels with both borders (bottom and top).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to display xAxis lines for position BOTH_SIDED but without labels on the bottom, so you need to override XAxisRenderer:

```
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    chart.setXAxisRenderer(new XAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(), chart.getXAxis(), chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)) {
        @Override
        public void renderAxisLabels(Canvas canvas) {
            if (!mXAxis.isEnabled()|| !mXAxis.isDrawLabelsEnabled())
                return;
            MPPointF pointF = MPPointF.getInstance(0f, 0f);
            mAxisLabelPaint.setTypeface(mXAxis.getTypeface());
            mAxisLabelPaint.setTextSize(mXAxis.getTextSize());
            mAxisLabelPaint.setColor(mXAxis.getTextColor());
            pointF.x = 0.5f;
            pointF.y = 1.0f;
            drawLabels(canvas, mViewPortHandler.contentTop() - mXAxis.getYOffset(), pointF);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it but it draws a black border around the whole graph. The left Y-axis has to be invisible (like on the screenshot).

Comment: Yes, this is working. It looks good but I wait for a while if there isn't some one-line answer :) If not I will accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah there is one liner. Create a separate class for this renderer and then set it in one line ;) I've looked through the source code of the library and there is no other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help the original author, but I had the same issue and fixed it with
  chart.setExtraBottomOffset(-40f);
Nice, simple, worth a try. You may need to tune the value to suit your aesthetic.